# How do I create this ui in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOwId.jpg)
I am new to flutter and saw this ui on net, trying to replicate it but not able to find the good solution.Can anyone please help me in this?

I tried grid view builder but couldn't replicate it same as it is.

Comment: you could check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751616/how-to-create-table-like-ui-in-flutter this should help your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your UI can be created using Table class and Widgets. Please check the  documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html